# No constructor found in the absence of writeln

Tags: oop, compiler-errors, d

I am using DMD64 D Compiler v2.063.2 on Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.

I have written a class as below:

```
class FixedList(T){
    // list
    private T[] list;

    // number of items
    private size_t numberOfItems;

    // capacity
    private size_t capacity;

    // mutex
    private Mutex listMutex;

    // get capacity
    @property public size_t Capacity(){ return capacity; }
    @property public shared size_t Capacity(){ return capacity; }

    // constructor
    public this( size_t capacity ){
        // initialise
        numberOfItems = 0;
        this.capacity = capacity;

        writeln("Cons Normal");
    }

    // constructor
    public shared this( size_t capacity ){
        // initialise
        numberOfItems = 0;
        this.capacity = capacity;

        // create mutex
        listMutex = cast(shared)(new Mutex());

        writeln("Cons Shared");
    }
}
```

While class is written in this way, in main function, I wrote that code:

```
auto list1 = new shared FixedList!int( 128 );
auto list2 = new FixedList!int( 128 );
```

Output with this, there is no error at all and the output is as below:

```
Cons Shared
Cons Normal
```

What I do next is to remove both `writeln` lines from the code, and when I recompile the code, it starts showing error messages as below:

```
src/webapp.d(61): Error: constructor lists.FixedList!(int).FixedList.this called with argument types:
    ((int) shared)
matches both:
    lists.d(28): lists.FixedList!(int).FixedList.this(ulong capacity)
and:
    lists.d(37): lists.FixedList!(int).FixedList.this(ulong capacity)
src/app.d(61): Error: no constructor for FixedList
src/app.d(62): Error: constructor lists.FixedList!(int).FixedList.this called with argument types:
    ((int))
matches both:
    lists.d(28): lists.FixedList!(int).FixedList.this(ulong capacity)
and:
    lists.d(37): lists.FixedList!(int).FixedList.this(ulong capacity)
src/app.d(62): Error: no constructor for FixedList
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Basically `writeln` function is preventing the error. Actually `writeln` is preventing in many places and I am not sure about why this is happening.

I even tried to compile the the code with `m32` flag for 32-bit, but it is still same. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pure`, `nothrow`, and `@safe` are inferred for template functions. As `FixedList` is templated, its constructors are templated. `writeln` is not (and cannot be) `pure` as it does I/O. So, while `writeln` is in the constructors, they are inferred to not be `pure`, but everything else that the constructors are doing is `pure`, so without the calls to `writeln`, they become `pure`.

Under some circumstances, the compiler is able to alter the return type of `pure` functions to implicitly convert it to `immutable` or `shared`. This works, because in those cases, the compiler knows that what's being returned is a new, unique object and that casting it to `immutable` or `shared` would not violate the type system. Not all `pure` functions qualify, as the parameter types can affect whether the compiler can guarantee that the return value is unique, but many `pure` functions are able to take advantage of this and implicitly convert their return value to `immutable` or `shared`. This is useful, because it can avoid code duplication (for different return types) or copying - since if the type returned doesn't match what you need with regards to `immutable` or `shared`, and you can't guarantee that it's not referred to elsewhere, you have to copy it to get the type that you want. In this case, the compiler is able to make the guarantee that the object is not referred to elsewhere, so it can safely cast it for you.

Constructors effectively return new values, so they can be affected by this feature. This makes it so that if a constructor is `pure`, you can often construct `immutable` and `shared` values from it without having to duplicate the constructor (like you'd have to do if it weren't `pure`). As with other `pure` functions, whether this works or not depends on the constructor's parameter types, but it's frequently possible, and it helps avoid code duplication.

What's causing you problems is that when `FixedList`'s constructors are both `pure`, the compiler is able to use either of them to construct a `shared` object. So, it doesn't know which one to choose, and gives you an ambiguity error.

I've reported this as a [bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=10653) on the theory that the compiler should probably prefer the constructer which is explicitly marked as `shared`, but what the compiler devs will decide, I don't know. The ability to implicitly convert return values from `pure` functions is a fairly new feature and exactly when we can and can't do those implicit conversions is still being explored, which can result both in unanticipated problems (like this one probably is) as well as compiler bugs (e.g. there's at least one case with `immutable`, where it currently does the conversion when it shouldn't). I'm sure that these issues will be ironed out fairly quickly though.

Answer (score 2):

A `pure` constructor can build a `shared` object without being marked `shared` itself.

Apparently, pureness is inferred for constructors.

`writeln` is not `pure`. So, with it in place, the constructors are not `pure`.

When `writeln` is removed, the constructors become `pure`. Both constructors now match the `shared` call.

Comment: Hmm. I thought when e try to create a shared object, especially shared constructor was chosen. I read the `pure function` in documentation, but couldn't have found anything about it.

Comment: @user2587136 Purity is not inferred for constructors. It is inferred for templated functions, and the entire class is templated, so the constructor is templated.